# Conditional joins on concatenated column in R

Tags: r, join, dplyr

I have datasets of the below formats:

```
CustomerId   City    ProductID     Related_Products 

    1         A         102         100,102,103,104,105
    1         A         105         102, 200, 302
    2         B         234         100, 202
    3         C         340         343, 432
    4         C         400         401
```

and

```
ProductID     City      OfferID
  102          A          1000
  100          A          1001
  401          C          1002
```

I want to join these 2 tables such that if the ProductID in 2nd table appears in the Related_Products column in the first table and the corresponding city is a match, then customer should be notified of the offers for that product.

Final Output:

```
CustomerId   City    ProductID     Related_Products         Offers

    1         A         102         100,102,103,104,105     1000, 1001
    1         A         105         102, 200, 302            NA
    2         B         234         100, 202                 NA   
    3         C         340         343, 432                 NA
    4         C         400         401                      1002
```

Note : All numbers are IDs, the Related_Products column is a string concatenated column but I can also make into a list(instead of comma separated strings) of this format:

```
CustomerId   City    ProductID     Related_Products                  Offers

    1         A         102         list(100,102,104,105,401)         1001,1000
    1         A         105         list(102, 200, 302)                NA
    2         B         234         list(100, 202)                     NA   
    3         C         340         list(343, 432)                     NA
    4         C         400         list(401)                         1002
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `separate_rows` from `tidyr`, we can bring `df1` in long format, do a `left_join` on `df2` and convert the data into comma-separated values grouped by `CustomerId, ProductID, City`.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
 tidyr::separate_rows(Related_Products, convert = TRUE) %>%
 left_join(df2, by = c("City" = "City", "Related_Products" = "ProductID")) %>%
  group_by(CustomerId, ProductID, City) %>%
  summarise(Related_Products = toString(Related_Products), 
            Offer = toString(na.omit(OfferID)))

#  CustomerId ProductID City  Related_Products        Offer     
#       <int>     <int> <chr> <chr>                   <chr>     
#1          1       102 A     100, 102, 103, 104, 105 1001, 1000
#2          1       105 A     102, 200, 302           1000      
#3          2       234 B     100, 202                ""        
#4          3       340 C     343, 432                ""        
#5          4       400 C     401                     1002
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(CustomerId = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), City = c("A", 
"A", "B", "C", "C"), ProductID = c(102L, 105L, 234L, 340L, 400L
), Related_Products = c("100,102,103,104,105", "102,200,302", 
"100,202", "343,432", "401")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-5L))

df2 <- structure(list(ProductID = c(102L, 100L, 401L), City = c("A", 
"A", "C"), OfferID = 1000:1002), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `regex_left_join` from `fuzzyjoin`

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
regex_left_join(df1, df2, by = c("Related_Products" = "ProductID", "City")) %>% 
    group_by(CustomerId, City = City.x, 
           ProductID = ProductID.x, Related_Products) %>%
    summarise(OfferID = str_c(OfferID, collapse=","))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(CustomerId = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), City = c("A", 
        "A", "B", "C", "C"), ProductID = c(102L, 105L, 234L, 340L, 400L
        ), Related_Products = c("100,102,103,104,105", "102, 200, 302", 
        "100, 202", "343, 432", "401")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
        -5L))

df2 <- structure(list(ProductID = c(102L, 100L, 401L), City = c("A", 
        "A", "C"), OfferID = 1000:1002), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
        -3L))
```